# Leanback ListRow Scroll in Center Of Screen

Tags: android, android-tv, android-launcher, leanback, listrowpresenter

I Have a `BrowseFragment` (leanback) and add 5 `ListRow` into adapter's BrowseFragment.
My problem is when the list row select this scroll while set in center of screen.
I want set this in bottom of screen.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: did you find any way out?

Comment: i think that put the my items list in bottom of rowList and increse the size of row list =)))